# Problemas con composer al instalar composer require maatwebsite/excel

Tags: laravel-5, composer

al quererinstalar `composer require maatwebsite/excel` para obtener unos datos en excel me tira este error

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.0.0 requires maatwebsite/excel ^2.0 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[2.0.1, 2.0.11, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.1.10, 2.1.11, 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.1.14, 2.1.15, 2.1.16, 2.1.17, 2.1.18, 2.1.19, 2.1.20, 2.1.21, 2.1.22, 2.1.23, 2.1.24, 2.1.25, 2.1.26, 2.1.27, 2.1.28, 2.1.29, 2.1.30, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.10, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.0.0 requires maatwebsite/excel ^2.0 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[2.0.1, 2.0.11, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.1.10, 2.1.11, 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.1.14, 2.1.15, 2.1.16, 2.1.17, 2.1.18, 2.1.19, 2.1.20, 2.1.21, 2.1.22, 2.1.23, 2.1.24, 2.1.25, 2.1.26, 2.1.27, 2.1.28, 2.1.29, 2.1.30, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.10, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.0.0 requires maatwebsite/excel ^2.0 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[2.0.1, 2.0.11, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.1.10, 2.1.11, 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.1.14, 2.1.15, 2.1.16, 2.1.17, 2.1.18, 2.1.19, 2.1.20, 2.1.21, 2.1.22, 2.1.23, 2.1.24, 2.1.25, 2.1.26, 2.1.27, 2.1.28, 2.1.29, 2.1.30, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.10, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons (locked at v3.0.0, required as 3.*) -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons[v3.0.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

No tengo idea de como resolverlo, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: que versión de laravel y composer estas usando?

Comment: version de composer `Composer version 1.5.3 2017-11-30 18:29:43` laravel 5.5

Comment: veo que el problema es que la versión de inslación de esa dependencia requiere una versión mayor a laravel 5.5 aquí la documentación https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/getting-started/installation.html para que cheques

Comment: entonces la linea ^5.5 tiene que ser mayor a esta?

Comment: si no estoy interpretando mal las indicaciones el símbolo ^ indica superior a; entonces conviene que te hagas un proyecto de prueba con la versión 5.7 por ejemplo la mas reciente y trata de instalar de nuevo el package de excel y me comentas

Comment: el problema esta en los datatables

Answer (score 1):

```
Version Laravel Version  Php Version    Support
2.1      <=5.6           <=7.0          Unsupported since 15-5-2018
3.0      ^5.5            ^7.0           Security fixes till 31-12-2018
3.1      ^5.5            ^7.0           New features
```

siempre verifica en la pagina oficial https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/

espero que te sea util